# How to call Firebase cloud function from React stream chat app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-functions, stream

Long story short, I'm knew to Firebase and I need to call this cloud function: "ext-auth-chat-getStreamUserToken" . The trigger is a HTTPS request to: https://europe-west2-FIREBASE-USER-INFO/ext-auth-chat-getStreamUserToken

Context: I've built a messaging app using Stream.io, with hard-coded user data and a placeholder token. Here's the key bit of code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function init() {
      const chatClient = StreamChat.getInstance(apiKey)

      await chatClient.connectUser(user, chatClient.devToken(user.id))

      const channel = chatClient.channel("messaging", "war-chat", {
        image:
          "https://i.picsum.photos/id/1006/200/200.jpg?hmac=yv53p45TOMz8bY4ZXUVRMFMO0_6d5vGuoWtE2hJhxlc",
        name: "Oli",
        members: [user.id],
        //chat description
      })

      await channel.watch()

      setClient(chatClient)
    }

    init()
    if (client) return () => client.disconnectUser()
  }, [])
```

I have installed the 'authenticate with stream chat' extension on Firebase. This creates various cloud functions, include one which creates a new user on Stream when a new user is created on firebase.

The only thing I need to do is modify this bit of code, to integrate firebase with stream chat:

```
await chatClient.connectUser(user, chatClient.devToken(user.id))
```

I can sort the user object. but how do I call the cloud function to get the token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [source code](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-firebase-extensions/blob/59df257d810bf2d1e25e4a4a0320df9e533b2fcd/auth-chat/functions/src/index.ts#L35) of the `getStreamUserToken` Cloud Function (linked on the [extension's product page](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stream-auth-chat)), it is a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

```js
export const getStreamUserToken = functions.handler.https.onCall((data, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

Calling the Cloud Function can be done using the Firebase Client SDKs as documented with examples [here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function). Because your cloud function resides in the `europe-west2` region (and not the default `us-central1` region), you will need to specify it when getting an instance of the [`Functions` builder class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/functions.functions):

```js
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

const functions = getFunctions(undefined, "europe-west2") // undefined is passed in so that the default app is used

const getStreamUserToken = functions.callable("ext-auth-chat-getStreamUserToken");

const streamUserToken = await getStreamUserToken();
```

The revoke function is called in the same way.

```js
const revokeStreamUserToken = functions.callable("ext-auth-chat-revokeStreamUserToken");

await revokeStreamUserToken();
```

Comment: Thanks so much Sam, this is really helpful and I have a much clearer idea about how this works! For the benefit of anyone else who stumbles across this, I had to implement it slightly differently but still along the liens of what you have suggested:
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

const functions = getFunctions(app, "europe-west2");
      const getToken =httpsCallable(functions, "ext-auth-chat-getStreamUserToken")
   const token = await getToken()
   const streamToken = token.data.toString()